# Чат с websocket

Tags: javascript, jquery

на сайте https://m.habr.com/post/200866/ написана статья как создать чат, скажите пожалуйста что такое и как сделать на хостинге пункт "установка зависимостей", это самое первое действие, и последнее запуск чата, тоже самое как это сделать на хостинге

Comment: "что такое и как сделать на хостинге пункт "установка зависимостей"..."

Это установка зависимостей. Или вам рассказать, что такое "установка пакетов в Linux"?

Comment: Вот коммент поддерживаю....

Comment: Не обязательно `linux`, может быть и `win`...  Это `NodeJS сервер`, и установка зависимостей `NPM пакетов` для `node`

Comment: Это от хостинга зависит. На обычном PHP/MySQL'ном обычно никак.